# Can a bitwise OR (|) be used in place of a logical OR (||)?

Tags: c

I found the following piece of code:

```
/* WMF or IF2 frames */
if ((input_format == MIME_IETF) | (input_format == IF2)) {
  ....
```

Source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/android-7.1.2_r11/media/libstagefright/codecs/amrnb/dec/src/amrdecode.cpp#414

I don't believe this is the programmer's real intention.  But I found it can't cause real problem.  I want to know if this will cause problem.

Comment: "Will this error cause a problem?" "Will this **error** cause a **problem**?" Self-explanatory. Error=problem. Fix it.

Comment: Can you tell me what's the problem will cause here? this is not my code, this is an open source project.

Comment: Why do you think that this will cause a problem?

Comment: I dont think this cause a problem, though it's not  the programmer's real intention.

Comment: Please give useful comments, guys.

Comment: Without any context, your question makes very little sense.

Comment: I'll try again. Why don't you think that this expresses the programmer's intention?

Comment: @DavidBowling I never said it didn't, but without any context, your question doesn't make sense. I can't say what I feel about it because it isn't even clear what you're asking.

Comment: @DavidBowling I can't understand what you mean. I think this is not the programmer's intention.

Comment: Sorry, @Carcigenicate, my comment was directed to OP, not you :)

Comment: some guys want to see the context, here is the link:https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/android-7.1.2_r11/media/libstagefright/codecs/amrnb/dec/src/amrdecode.cpp#414

Comment: @DavidBowling Whoops, sorry. I'm tired. Didn't notice you weren't the OP lol.

Comment: @jiych.guru-- do you think that the programmer intended `if ((input_format == MIME_IETF) || (input_format == IF2)) {}`? That is, logical or instead of bitwise or?

Comment: Which language? You taged for two very different languages. Pick one!

Answer (score 3):

With a logical "or" the 2nd half is only evaluated if the first half is *false*.

```
if ((input_format == MIME_IETF) || (input_format == IF2)) {
```

With a bit-wise "or", both arguments are evaluated.

```
if ((input_format == MIME_IETF) | (input_format == IF2)) {
```

With OP's code of `if ((input_format == MIME_IETF) | (input_format == IF2)) {`, likely little difference.

> I want to know if this will cause problem.

If `input_format, IF2, MIME_IETF` are all a simple variables or constants, the *functionality* is the same here using `|` or `||`.  A compiler may even emit the same code.

I suggest to code what is most understandable.  As it is now, the problem it has caused is an unneeded pause in code review.

Answer (score 0):

The result of equality operator `==` is either 0 or 1.  From section 6.5.9 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *3* The `==` (equal  to)  and `!=` (not  equal  to)  operators  are  analogous  to  the  relational operators  except  for  their  lower 
>   precedence. **Each  of  the  operators  yields  1  if  the specified 
>   relation  is  true  and  0  if  it  is  false.**   The  result  has 
>   type `int` .  For  any  pair  of operands, exactly one of the
>   relations is true.

This means that the result can have no more than the least significant bit set, meaning that a bitwise OR (`|`) of the operands is equivalent to a logical OR (`||`) of the operands.

Now to demonstrate.  Ignoring for a moment the actual operands to each `==` operator, there are 4 possible outcomes:

```
0 | 0 == 0
0 | 1 == 1
1 | 0 == 1
1 | 1 == 1
```

If we instead use the `||` operator, we have:

```
0 || 0 == 0
0 || 1 == 1
1 || 0 == 1
1 || 1 == 1
```

Given the expression, it looks like a logical OR is the actual intent, so it is probably better to use the `||` operator here to avoid confusing the reader.